# Geth --syncmode full takes too long

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, full-node

I'm trying to synchronize a full `geth` node and after 3 days of synchronizing in a 2TB Samsung SSD with great internet connection, I'm at ~40%:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 5793255,
  healedBytecodeBytes: 0,
  healedBytecodes: 0,
  healedTrienodeBytes: 0,
  healedTrienodes: 0,
  healingBytecode: 0,
  healingTrienodes: 0,
  highestBlock: 14790910,
  startingBlock: 5304492,
  syncedAccountBytes: 0,
  syncedAccounts: 0,
  syncedBytecodeBytes: 0,
  syncedBytecodes: 0,
  syncedStorage: 0,
  syncedStorageBytes: 0
}

> console.log(100* eth.syncing.currentBlock / eth.syncing.highestBlock);
39.17067306879699

INFO [05-17|09:29:38.349] Imported new chain segment               blocks=31   txs=4463  mgas=203.282  elapsed=8.306s      mgasps=24.474  number=5,794,214 hash=3745fa..1d1606 age=3y11mo3w  dirty=1021.34MiB

INFO [05-17|09:29:46.362] Imported new chain segment               blocks=40   txs=4918  mgas=243.038  elapsed=8.012s      mgasps=30.331  number=5,794,254 hash=cd2e9c..d409eb age=3y11mo3w  dirty=1020.20MiB
```

I used the following command to synchronize:

```
./geth --datadir /media/workstation/MySSD/ethereum --http --http.port 8545 --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.corsdomain '*' --http.vhosts "*" -- syncmode full console
```

Any idea why this is taking so long?...
Is it normal what is happening?

Comment: It's taking so long because the Ethereum state is huge, plus a full sync means re-executing absolutely everything. The current block is 14791331, so you did around 40% of it, just be patient, you should be done in a few days. Alternatively, you could switch to another sync mode, but given that you are already almost halfway there, I'd just let if finish.

Comment: @hroussille thing is, i need it to be full. so you say it's normal that it takes this long. thanks!

Comment: Yes because you are requesting headers, and blocks body then re-executing everything to ensure it's valid... it takes a lot of IO and therefore time.

Comment: It takes long; this is the way it is...